# Apache Load Balancer - URL Redirect to internal IP

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing

I am trying to setup a simple Loadbalancer in Apache as below

My single node Load balancer is on internal IP 192.168.1.3 with this configuration

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ProxyRequests off        
            ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
            # this is my external Static IP 
            <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.2
                    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.3
                    Require all granted
                    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
            </Proxy>
            <Location /balancer-manager>
                    SetHandler balancer-manager
                    Require host example.org
            </Location>
            ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
            ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    </VirtualHost>
```

I have set on my router to forward all http requests to my Load balancer 192.168.1.3

Now when I try to access my application on system that is on a different network as that of servers as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx I get redirected 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3 alternatively. Since I am on different network these redirects are meaningless. How do I solve this such that my setup works when accessed from external IP ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this configuration, and works correctly:

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyTimeout 300


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy balancer://myClusterBalancer>
        BalancerMember http://192.168.1.2
        BalancerMember http://192.168.1.3
        ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / balancer://myClusterBalancer/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse /  balancer://myClusterBalancer/
</VirtualHost>
```