# Apache2: How to Proxy the same url with different ports?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, apache2, proxypass

we have multiple different /apex instances.
now we want to proxy the requests trough an Apache2-Server like this:

```
request for instance1: http://proxy:8080/apex -> http://apex1:8080
request for instance2: http://proxy:8081/apex -> http://apex2:8080
```

this could be solved trough the following VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ProxyPass /apex/ http://apex1:8080/apex/
ProxypassReverse /apex/ http://apex1:8080/apex/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
ProxyPass /apex/ http://apex2:8080/apex/
ProxypassReverse /apex/ http://apex2:8080/apex/
</VirtualHost>
```

but if enabled another virtualhost quits working
It's like the other VirtualHosts overwrites the <VirtualHost *:*> matcher

```
Alias /server-info /opt/www/
<VirtualHost *:*>
        <Directory "/srv/www/">
                Allow from all
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Password Required"
                Require valid-user
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                DirectoryIndex  side.html
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: take a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/762189/apache-load-balancer-url-redirect-to-internal-ip)

Comment: How could this help me? My question is not about loadbalancing

Comment: the function of apache is imho the same

Comment: I updated my question. I think request 1, request 2 was not a good choice

Comment: The apex instances are totaly different, we dont want to switch between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved, with the following config

```
Alias /server-info /opt/www/
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9000>
        <Directory "/srv/www/">
                Allow from all
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Password Required"
                Require valid-user
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                DirectoryIndex  side.html
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

ProxyPass /server-info/ http://127.0.0.1:9000/server-info-new/
ProxypassReverse /server-info/ http://127.0.0.1:9000/server-info-new/
```

through the proxypass /server-info can be accessed from any port